# Android- gestureDetector onLongPress and onDown

Tags: android, events, gesture

I'm using gesture to capture the touch event, but it fire the two events when i longPress.
how i can disable onDown event when i hold press?
this is my code.

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,
                                "long" + position + counter++,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,
                                "touch" + position + counter++,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
        category.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `abstract boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)`.
The callback `public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)` you are using is fired on the start of all gestures (when finger touches the screen).
Whether the gesture is just single tap, long press or any other can be detected only on the end of the gesture (when you release your finger).

Answer (score 0):

As kotucz said, `onDown` is fired on the start of all gestures. Using `onSingleTapUp` instead of `onDown` is a workable alternative.

However, if you need `MotionEvent` information that is not available with `onSingleTapUp`, like mouse info (e.g. `event.isButtonPressed(MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY)`), you still need `onDown` which provides such info. In this case you should implement

- `onDown` that handles the extra info and consumes the event or not (i.e. returns true or false respectively), depending on your business case
- `onSingleTapUp` for the cases where `onDown` has not consumed the event
- `onLongPress` for the cases where `onDown` has not consumed the event